# Unable to show success alert message on website post email sent request via modal dialog on .net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a pop up modal dialog on my website that i use to send an appointment request to admin email. I am able to send the request but not able to show success/a failure alert message to user post the request is complete. i am using asp .net mvc on visual studio 2017

modal html:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalAppointment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalAppointmentLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalAppointmentLabel">Appointment</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="#">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="appointment_name" class="text-black">Full Name*</label>
                            <input id="getAppointmentFullName" type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="appointment_phone" class="text-black">Phone*</label>
                                    <input id="getAppointmentPhone" type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="appointment_email" class="text-black">Email</label>
                                    <input id="getAppointmentEmail" type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="appointment_date" class="text-black">Date*</label>
                                    <input id="appointment_date" type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="appointment_time" class="text-black">Time*</label>
                                    <input id="appointment_time" type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="appointment_service" class="text-black">Choose the Service* (at least one)</label>
                                <div class="checkboxInline"><input id="ivf" type="checkbox" name="serviceType" value="IVF">IVF<br> </div>
                                <div class="checkboxInline"><input id="derma" type="checkbox" name="serviceType" value="Dermatolology"> Dermatolology<br></div>
                                <div class="checkboxInline"><input id="lapro" type="checkbox" name="serviceType" value="Laproscopy"> Laproscopy<br> </div>
                                <div class="checkboxInline"> <input id="opto" type="checkbox" name="serviceType" value="Optometry"> Optometry<br> </div>
                                <div class="checkboxInline">   <input id="gm" type="checkbox" name="serviceType" value="General Medicine"> General Medicine<br> </div>
                                <div class="checkboxInline">
                                    <input id="physio" type="checkbox" name="serviceType" value="Physiotherapy"> Physiotherapy<br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkboxInline">
                                    <input id="ortho" type="checkbox" name="serviceType" value="Orthopedic"> Orthopedic<br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkboxInline">
                                    <input id="pedia" type="checkbox" name="serviceType" value="Pediatric"> Pediatrics<br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkboxInline">
                                    <input id="gynae" type="checkbox" name="serviceType" value="Obs & Gynae"> Obs and Gynae<br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="appointment_message" class="text-black">Message</label>
                            <textarea id="appointment_message" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="getAppointmentSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" data-loading-text="Submitting...." class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

click method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $("#btnRequestAppointment").click(function () {
                $("#modalAppointment").modal('show');
            });
            $("#getAppointmentSubmit").click(function () {
                var name = $("#getAppointmentFullName").val();
                var contactNumber = $("#getAppointmentPhone").val();
                var email = $("#getAppointmentEmail").val();
                var date = $("#appointment_date").val();
                var time = $("#appointment_time").val();
                var comments = $("#appointment_message").val();
                var servicesNeeded = [];
                $("input:checked").each(function () {
                    servicesNeeded.push($(this).val());
                });
                if ($.trim(name).length == 0 || $.trim(contactNumber).length == 0 || $.trim(date).length == 0 ||
                    $.trim(time).length == 0 || servicesNeeded.length == 0) {
                    alert('Fields marked with * are mandatory. Please enter them all and click Submit.');
                };
                var detail = {
                    Name: name, ContactNumber: contactNumber, Email: email, ServicesNeeded: servicesNeeded, Date: date,
                    Time: time, Comments: comments
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Home/RequestAppointment',
                    data: JSON.stringify(detail),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        var response = JSON.parse(result.responseText);                       
                        if (response && response.emailSent == "sent") {
                            $("#modalAppointment").modal('hide');
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        $("#modalAppointment").modal('hide');
                        alert("Error has occurred..");  
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

controller action:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> RequestAppointment(AppointmentDetailsModel appointmentRequest)
        {
            appointmentRequest.Validate();
            //var result = false;
            string message = $"Appointment request from: {appointmentRequest.Name}; Phone Number: {appointmentRequest.ContactNumber}. They are looking to get: " +
               $"{string.Join(",", appointmentRequest.ServicesNeeded)} services on Date: {appointmentRequest.Date} at Time {appointmentRequest.Time}. Message: {appointmentRequest.Comments}";
            var response = await SendEmail(message);
            if (response == "sent")
                return Json(new { emailSent = "sent" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else
                return Json(new { emailSent = "failed" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: you can add debugger inside success and error of ajax

Comment: hi @AsifRaza.. "debugger" doesnt seem to work inside ajax call

Comment: what are you getting inside --- ... success: function (result) { after it add "debugger" debug it

Answer (score 0):

You're using `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` and controller action without any HTTP method attribute (remember the default HTTP method is `GET` when not specified) but your AJAX request has `type: "POST"` option, which never reach the controller action because it has different HTTP method.

You need to either change AJAX request to use `type: "GET"`, or decorate the controller with `[HttpPost]` attribute (and remove `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`) instead:

**GET version**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Home/RequestAppointment',
    data: JSON.stringify(detail),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        var response = JSON.parse(result.responseText);                       
            if (response && response.emailSent == "sent") {
                $("#modalAppointment").modal('hide');
                alert(response);
            }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            $("#modalAppointment").modal('hide');
            alert("Error has occurred..");  
    }
});
```

**POST version**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> RequestAppointment(AppointmentDetailsModel appointmentRequest)
{
    appointmentRequest.Validate();

    string message = $"Appointment request from: {appointmentRequest.Name}; Phone Number: {appointmentRequest.ContactNumber}. They are looking to get: " +
    $"{string.Join(",", appointmentRequest.ServicesNeeded)} services on Date: {appointmentRequest.Date} at Time {appointmentRequest.Time}. Message: {appointmentRequest.Comments}";
    var response = await SendEmail(message);
    if (response == "sent")
        return Json(new { emailSent = "sent" });
    else
        return Json(new { emailSent = "failed" });
}
```

**Update:**

Based on the AJAX success result, it seems this line below causing problem because `result.responseText` may return `undefined` because the property may not exist inside `result`:

```
var response = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
```

If you want to fetch `emailSent`, just use `result.emailSent` instead:

```
if (typeof result !== "undefined" && result != null) {
    $("#modalAppointment").modal('hide');
    alert(result.emailSent);
}
```

Comment: hi @tetsuya.. actually i have the [httppost] above my controller.. must have missed adding it on the code.. as i mentioned, my controller is being hit and emails are sent.. but the problem is showing "alerts" to the user

Comment: Seems that `responseText` in `success` causing the issue, check the edited one.

Comment: Made the change... still no luck @tetsuya

Comment: Ok i did some more debugging using the "console" window on google chrome.. it seems that the alert dialog is coming up but somehow the browser window isnt showing it.. is it because my page is getting refreshed when it comes back from the "controller" back to the shared layout?? @tetsuya